# VBScript getting results from Shell

Tags: scripting, vbscript, wsh, windows-scripting

```
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WSCript.shell")
wshshell.run "runas ..."
```

How do I get the results and display in a MsgBox

Comment: Define "results". Runas exit code? Exit code of the application run via runas? The application's console output?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You will want to use the WshShell object's Exec method instead of Run.  Then simply read the command line's output from the standard streams.  Try this one:

```
Const WshFinished = 1
Const WshFailed = 2
strCommand = "ping.exe 127.0.0.1"

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Exec(strCommand)

Select Case WshShellExec.Status
   Case WshFinished
       strOutput = WshShellExec.StdOut.ReadAll
   Case WshFailed
       strOutput = WshShellExec.StdErr.ReadAll
End Select

WScript.StdOut.Write strOutput  'write results to the command line
WScript.Echo strOutput          'write results to default output
MsgBox strOutput                'write results in a message box
```

Comment: Would we be able to do the same kind of thing with WshShell.Run?

Comment: No.  Run does not provide access to standard streams.

Comment: Note: This is asynchronous so you will likely see an incorrect `WshShellExec.Status` at `Select Case`

Comment: @MattBorja If you use it as intended, to run command line programs, it will run the command and return an object at completion. However, if you launch a windowed application such as calc.exe, you would need a loop since the command line would return before the program execution ended. In that case, you would simply loop until `WshShellExec.Status <> 0`.

Comment: @Nilpo, it fails using your own strCommand value. It returns 0 (meaning Running) Fixed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920690/vbscript-capturing-output-from-stdout

Comment: @ChrisJJ Please see my previous comment.

Comment: @Nilpo I had the same issue when running anything. As rdev5 said, `Exec` is asynch, so `WshShellExec.Status` is still 0 (running) at the time you first check it. You need to loop until it's done with something like `While WshShellExec.Status = 0 : WScript.Sleep 50 : Wend` Perhaps consider editing your answer.

Answer (score 9):

This is a modified version of Nilpo's answer that fixes the issue with `WshShell.Exec` being asynchronous. We do a busy-loop waiting until the shell's status is no longer running, and then we check the output. Change the command-line argument `-n 1` to a higher value to make `ping` take longer, and see that the script will wait longer until completion.

(If anyone has a true asynchronous, event-based solution to the problem, then please let me know!)

```
Option Explicit

Const WshRunning = 0
Const WshFinished = 1
Const WshFailed = 2

Dim shell : Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim exec : Set exec = shell.Exec("ping.exe 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 500")

While exec.Status = WshRunning
    WScript.Sleep 50
Wend

Dim output

If exec.Status = WshFailed Then
    output = exec.StdErr.ReadAll
Else
    output = exec.StdOut.ReadAll
End If

WScript.Echo output
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution of BoffinBrain still doesn't work, since exec.Status doesn't return an error level (returns just 0 while running and 1 when finished). For that purpose you must use exec.ExitCode (Returns the exit code set by a script or program run using the Exec() method.). So the solution changes to

```
Option Explicit

Const WshRunning = 0
' Const WshPassed = 0    ' this line is useless now
Const WshFailed = 1

Dim shell : Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim exec : Set exec = shell.Exec("ping.exe 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 500")

While exec.Status = WshRunning
    WScript.Sleep 50
Wend

Dim output

If exec.ExitCode = WshFailed Then
    output = exec.StdErr.ReadAll
Else
    output = exec.StdOut.ReadAll
End If

WScript.Echo output
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this makes the most sense.  It is WshFinished, not WshFailed.
I print the output as it comes, instead of at the end.

```
Function ExecCommand(cmd)
    Const WshRunning = 0
    Const WshFinished = 1

    Dim objWshShell : Set objWshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim oExec : Set oExec = objWshShell.Exec(cmd)

    Do
        Finished = ( oExec.Status = WshFinished )

        While oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream <> True
            WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(oExec.StdOut.ReadLine())
        Wend

        While oExec.StdErr.AtEndOfStream <> True
            WScript.StdErr.WriteLine("ERROR: " & oExec.StdErr.ReadLine())

        WScript.StdOut.WriteLine("ExitCode: " & oExec.ExitCode)
        Wend

        WScript.Sleep 100
    Loop Until Finished
End Function
```

A good example is:
`ExecCommand "ping.exe 127.0.0.1 -n 3 -w 500"`

See error output with:
 `ExecCommand "cmd /c Echo Test Error >&2"`

Answer (score 0):

```
var errorlevel = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell').Run(command, 0, true)
```

the third parameter must be true, and errorlevel will be return value, check if it is equal 0.

Comment: Not VBScript; not (std) out (put).

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner I test code in jscript, and I think vbscript is ok too

Comment: as you can see from the other answer, your assumption is wrong.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner no, if the third parameter is true, the return value will be errorlevel