# Make sendKeys faster

Tags: vbscript, sendkeys, wsh

I'm trying to create a program that will open "command prompt" and open a specific port using "sendKeys". Here is my code:

```
Set Keys = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.ShellExecute "cmd.exe","runas", 1
Sleep(0.01)
Keys.sendKeys "{ENTER}"
Sleep(0.01)
Keys.sendKeys "rem Open TCP Port 407 inbound and outbound"
Keys.sendKeys "{ENTER}"
Keys.sendKeys "netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=""EXAMPLE"" dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP localport=407"
Keys.sendKeys "{ENTER}"
Keys.sendKeys "netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=""EXAMPLE""  protocol=TCP dir=out localport=407 action=""allow"""
Keys.sendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

I think that the keys are not fast enough.

I don't want to use `Keys.run "cmd [code]"` because then an Antivirus might think that the program is a virus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using SendKeys (which you would usually use a last resort for programs that don't have command-line support), you can use WShell to execute commands directly and get the output from StdOut or StdErr. The added advantage is you can check the return status and the output to see whether your commands succeeded or failed.

[See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45284000/534406) as an example, but I'll include it here for your convenience:

```
Option Explicit

Const WshRunning = 0
Const WshFinished = 1
Const WshFailed = 2

Dim shell : Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim exec : Set exec = shell.Exec("ping.exe 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 500")

While exec.Status = WshRunning
    WScript.Sleep 50
Wend

Dim output

If exec.Status = WshFailed Then
    output = exec.StdErr.ReadAll
Else
    output = exec.StdOut.ReadAll
End If

WScript.Echo output
```

Alternatively, instead of executing multiple WScript shells in succession, you can write your commands into a pre-made batch file and execute that.

Answer (score 0):

There is another method to do this. Not expert with the antivirus software... You may check if this suites you.

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set oExec = oShell.exec("%comspec%")

oExec.StdIn.Write "dir" & vbCrLf
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants to remove the delay:
Instead of doing

```
Set Keys = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Keys.sendKeys "a"
    Keys.sendKeys "{ENTER}"
    Keys.sendKeys "b"
    Keys.sendKeys "{ENTER}"
    Keys.sendKeys "c"
    Keys.sendKeys "{ENTER}
```

do

```
Set Keys = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Keys.sendKey "a{ENTER}b{ENTER}c{ENTER}"
```

It's messy, but it's WAY faster.