# Get output when using .run

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I'm trying to run a program that will web scrape from Pastebin using PowerShell. I used the following code to do so:

```
Set Wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Wshell.Run "%ComSpec% /c powershell & $result = Invoke-WebRequest 
""https://pastebin.com/raw/wAhYB4UY"" & $result.content ", 0, True
```

`$result.content` will bring up everything I need from Pastebin. How can I transfer `$result.content` to a VBScript variable?

I know this is possible using the `Exec()` method as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060876/vbscript-getting-results-from-shell), but I can't use it because I want my code to stay hidden, which to my knowledge is not possible with `Exec()` (without having a window popping and closing)

I also don't want to use File I/O in Powershell because that can really complicate other things I want my program to do in the future; however, If absolutely no options are available, then I can use it.

EDIT: Some readers pointed out that my script only consists of running Powershell, so why not program my script in PowerShell? Well, not everything I am planning for this script to do can be done in PS. for example, I want my script to type some stuff outside of PS. I also want to wait until the user has pressed a certain key, in my case PrtSc (which will create a popup a message using MsgBox).

Comment: Why vbscript?  What's the point of using powershell at that point

Comment: Agree - why run a PowerShell command from VBScript when you can just run it from PowerShell?

Comment: Anything you could do in batch or VBScript you could do in PowerShell too. And more. However, I find your continued dodging the question what you actually want to achieve with this code rather suspicious, so no cookies from me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Path = 'https://pastebin.com/raw/etc'
$Raw = Invoke-WebRequest $Path
$Raw.Content
```

What do you want to do with the data that using VBScript is the preferable tool?